# Can we connect Local Lambda function to Local MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have set up the local Lambda function (in Python) on my machine with the help of the SAM app and I also have installed the local MongoDB. I want to make a connection between the locally created Lambda function and MongoDB local.

My first question is "Is that possible to connect local MongoDB with local Lambda function?"
If yes, then please elaborate on how to do it? Any guide or tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: @AlexBlex your suggested solution isn't relevant to my query.

Comment: Aren't you trying to connect from SAM docker to local mongo on the host system? It is possible, and there are answers for different hosts OS, as it really depends. BTW, welcome to stackoverflow, we don't ask recommendations for 3rd party libraries, tools, or tutorials here.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you have mongoDB running in a docker container, I just recently figured this out the hard way.

```
docker pull mongo
docker run mongo
```

and then set the databaseuri for pymongo to `mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/'`and it should connect.